# RAM Configuration

Tags: memory

I have DL380 G5 server with 12GB(2GB stick each) of RAM and I want to add  16 GB (4Rx4)Can I do this or I need to have RAM with same configuration.like all 4GB sticks or all 2GB.

P.S Can use 4GB and 2GB sticks together. ?

Answer (score 2):

HP servers usually are very picky about the exact type and combinations of RAM you can use.
Only certain combinations are supported and you have to put the right size in the right slot.

If I recall correctly a DL380-G5 has 4 banks of 2 DIMM's each. They need DDR2-667 registered. ECC is optional (but don't pin me on that).
Each bank needs to have 2 identical DIMM's. These can be 1, 2 and 4 GB. (Not sure if 8 is supported.)

All the info you need you can get from the HP support pages on www.hp.com
A brief summary of this info is listed on the inside of the top-cover of the server as well.

Comment: Much better than my answer!

Comment: So can I do this
1A - 4GB
2C - 2GB
3A - 4GB
4C - 2GB
5B - 4GB
6D - 2GB
7B  - 4GB

Answer (score 1):

This memory has to be 'Fully-Buffered' memory as opposed to the Registered/Unregistered memory Tonny mentions, so make sure you get the right type, you don't give us a lot of details about the memory you have but I'm not sure what you have will work sorry.

That said you can use 1Gb, 2GB, 4GB and **8GB** DIMMS in the same box but Tonny is right, you need the same DIMMs in each 'alphabetical channel' - i.e. all in the 'A' slots have to match, all in the 'B' slots must too etc.

Take a look at [THIS](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12477_na/12477_na.html#Memory) section of the quickspecs.

Comment: You're right. They have to be fully buffered. I just pulled some RAM from a G5 to check. Some weeks ago we replaced a couple of G5 based VMWare clusters with G8's so I have something to play with :-)

Comment: We just got rid of all of our G5's so it was close in my mind, oh and don't forget, they're Gen8's - G8 means something very rude to the Japanese ;)

Comment: Really ? Now I'm curious. Must ask my Japanese colleague about that.

Comment: Pretty much their equivalent to our 'C-word'. Though I'm told they're sticking with 'Gen', certainly the G9 kit we've seen has 'Gen9' written on it.

Comment: use google translator for g8 meaning :P

Comment: Just checked. G8 is apparently typical SMS/Tweet slang for a part of the male anatomy. It appears in both Japanese and Mandarin Chinese.

Comment: How many RAM slots are available in g5 ?

Comment: 1A - 4GB 2C - 2GB 3A - 4GB 4C - 2GB 5B - 4GB 6D - 2GB 7B - 4GB 8D -2GB

Can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can mix the size of the RAM but it is not advisable to do so as you could possibly run into some problems further down the line, with reliability, speed, etc.

I would recommend looking on [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/) and making sure the RAM you buy also matches the motherboard on your server.